# Bash: how can I use read to echo (or do things to) an array member

Tags: arrays, bash, user-input

array content

```
someCommand=$(cat /etc/somelog) #pseudo
```

array creation

```
array=($someCommand)
```

array length

```
arrayLen=${#array[@]}
```

for loop iterates for array length

```
for (( i=0; i<${arrayLen}; i++ ));  
do
```

adds someprefix (for readability )

`$(($i + 1 ))` appends number list (for clear options) starting at 1

```
echo "$(($i + 1 )) ${arr[$i]/#/someprefix}"    


done        

printf "\n"
echo "Please enter 1-${arrayLen} --> "
```

asks the user for input

```
 read anwser
```

stores the value (a case statement woud be better
    # to replace the for loop as well - but this is a concept script) just trying to get it to work.

#### this is what I need help with ### (I think?)

```
    echo "${array[$anwser]}"   # do things to #
```

Comment: What is not working or what do you need help with? Getting any errors?

Comment: Everything I have tried when manipulating    echo "${array[$anwser]}" in to shape has ether been 1. empty 2. bad expansion.

Comment: The two phrases "concept script" and "trying to get it to work" doesn't fit together well. In order to make it work you'll now have to make it a *real* script. The syntax `${bar[$foo]}` is valid BASH syntax. It expands to the value associated with `$foo` in the array `$bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading to a variable named `$answer`, but indexing your array with `$anwser`.